# Must I make icons for iPad if it's an iPhone only app?

Tags: ios, xcode, icons, app-store

Must I make icons for iPad if it's an iPhone only app? Apple says, that it's not required. When I try to send my game using Application Loader, I see this.

[image]

Can I just delete `CFBundleIconFiles(iPad)` from `info.plist` ?

Comment: Even if it's only intended for use on iPhones, is there anything that prevents someone with an iPad from downloading/installing it? Why not just create the icons? I would imagine you have icons included for iPhone, why not just include the sizes for iPad?

Comment: @Mastrianni You know, in life you need to have principles. If there is a problem, I prefer not to avoid it.

Comment: @Mastrianni Second thing is that Apple adepts iPhone icons for iPad users who downloaded it.

Comment: The reason I ask is because it just makes sense to me to include icons for the other devices "just in case". I imagine some guy downloading it from the app store, and seeing some weird placeholder on his home screen instead of a nice fancy icon for your app. I've just never seen an app marked "iPhone only", which is why I was wondering if apple actually prevents iPad users from downloading it. Because if they don't, having iPad icons would be a safe bet. Although I suppose if it won't work on iPad then the icon would be the least of an iPad users problems. :)

Answer (score 2):

You do not need iPad icon files if your app is an iPhone-only one. Those errors can occur sometimes if the project isn't cleaned or if the resource files aren't copied into the project properly.

Make sure you've marked the app for iPhone only, and remove the iPad icon files from your `info.plist`, and also make sure all the files are copied in your `copy bundle sources`. To check this, go to

`Your project target > Build Phases > Copy Bundle Sources`

[image]

and clean your project pressing <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>alt ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

If that didn't work, delete the images from your project, drag and drop them again, and repeat the steps above.

Comment: Also in case someone has the same issue on Xcode 7+ check that image sets in Images.xcassets don't include iPad images. You can changes the Devices settings from Universal to iPhone only for each image in Utilities -> Attributes Inspector